# Elasticsearch phrase suggester

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I would like to use "[Phrase Suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html)". I've got a problem. When typing "johni depp",
it returns several results in this order:

1. john depp
2. johnny depp
3. joann depp
4. johnn depp

How can I sort the suggestions using json so that the first result is "johnny depp"?
I've tried doing this with a **phonetic indexer**, but without success.

This is my configuration:

Query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "johni depp",
      "fields": [
        "fullName.word"
      ],
      "operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "text": "johni depp",
    "film": {
      "phrase": {
        "analyzer": "whitespace-fullName",
        "field": "fullName.whitespace",
        "size": 5,
        "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
        "max_errors": 0.5,
        "gram_size": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": []
}
```

Indexer (I use Elastica, but it's same thing):

```
$elasticaIndex->create(
              array(
                  'number_of_shards'   => 4,
                  'number_of_replicas' => 1,
                  'analysis'           => array(
                      'analyzer' => array(
                          'autocomplete-index-fullName'  => array(
                              'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                              'filter'    => 'asciifolding, lowercase, edgeNGram'
                          ),
                          'autocomplete-search-fullName' => array(
                              'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                              'filter'    => 'asciifolding, lowercase'
                          ),
                          'word-fullName'                => array(
                              'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
                              'filter'    => 'lowercase'
                          ),
                          'whitespace-fullName'          => array(
                              'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                              'filter'    => 'lowercase'
                          ),
                      ),
                      'filter'   => array(
                          'edgeNGram' => array(
                              'type'     => 'edgeNGram',
                              'min_gram' => 1,
                              'max_gram' => 15
                          )
                      )
                  )
              ),
              false
);
```

Mapping :

```
$mapping->setProperties(
        array(
            'fullName' => array('type'   => 'string',
                                'fields' => array(
                                    'autocomplete' => array(
                                        'type'            => 'string',
                                        'index_analyzer'  => 'autocomplete-index-fullName',
                                        'search_analyzer' => 'autocomplete-search-fullName'
                                    ),
                                    'word'         => array(
                                        'type'            => 'string',
                                        'analyzer'  => 'word-fullName'
                                    ),
                                    'whitespace'   => array(
                                        'type'            => 'string',
                                        'analyzer'  => 'whitespace-fullName'
                                    ),
                                )),
        )
);
```

Examples of referenced values:

- John Cleese
- John Gemberling
- Johnny Hallyday
- Johnny Depp
- Joann Sfar
- Joanna Rytel
- Samuel Johnson
- Johnson Traoré

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want the "completion suggester" instead?

What I can recommend you, it's to use "both":

1. Search with basic completion suggester w/o fuzzy
2. Search with phrase suggester
3. Loop to (1) with fuzzy etc....